# How do I change a cell background through a web service?

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms, json.net, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion's SfCalendar for Xamarin, and I'm trying to get a true/false condition on each day shown based on a server response. If I change the cell background color before the petition is made, it will do so without a problem, but if I wait for its response, it won't change even if I'm on the main thread.

```
    public async Task CalDates(object sender, Syncfusion.SfCalendar.XForms.MonthCell args)
    {
        HttpClient hTTPClient = new HttpClient();
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Utils.Utils.baseUrl);
        Dictionary<string, string> dataToSend = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dataToSend.Add("session", Utils.Utils.session);
        dataToSend.Add("year", args.Date.Year.ToString());
        dataToSend.Add("month", args.Date.Month.ToString());
        dataToSend.Add("day", args.Date.Day.ToString());
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToSend, new KeyValuePairConverter());
        Debug.WriteLine(jsonData);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        //If I change backgrounds here, it will work
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/getPlan", content);
        //If I do it here, it won't work anymore
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var resultJson = JObject.Parse(result);
        if ((int)resultJson["status"] == 1)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(resultJson["data"]);
            if((bool)resultJson["data"] == true){
                try{
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {

                        args.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#e8de71");
                        args.TextColor = Color.Gray;
                    });
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If I do something else inside the BeginInvokeOnMainThread, like changing a label text or something not using the calendar, it will work. Please help me, I've been stuck with this for a while now and I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: You probably should use MessagingCenter.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give it a try